# Office-js - Getting row/column count of a large range

Tags: excel, office-js

So I'm working on an add-in that will be working with (by Excel standards) large datasets. To avoid running into the 5MB API limit, I'm attempting to chunk any reads/writes to the spreadsheet. Writing to the spreadsheet is fairly straightforward, but I'm running into a problem reading data from the spreadsheet. The plan is to use `worksheet.getUsedRange()` to get row/column counts, and read through the worksheet in chunks based on those counts.

However, in my test spreadsheet (which is a 500,000 x 3 sheet of randomly generated names), even the following will fail:

```js
var usedRange = worksheet.getUsedRange(true);
usedRange.load("rowCount, columnCount");
await ctx.sync()  // <- The failure happens here
```

That ctx.sync() will fail after about a minute due to a timeout (note that I don't get the API error citing the 5MB request/response limit, just a timeout)

Essentially my question is this: How do I effectively get the row count of a large range, or is there a better way to go about reading the contents of a large worksheet?

Comment: Is that possible to share your sample workbook to help identify the cause ? and which platform you are using ? Excel Desktop, Excel Online, Mac or others ?  I tried on Exel desktoo, It's quickly returned for me

Comment: As for your question, you loaded the properties on demand and group context.sync() properly based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization#excel-add-ins mentioned, so it looks good to me.

Comment: Hi @MandytMSFT - sorry for the late reply. The issue actually resolved itself. Considering I also had some definite syntax errors that I didn't initially hit, I think I was dealing with some sort of caching issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, Glad to see issue has been resolved!